# How can I bind right-mouse-click event to proc in Tcl?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am working on linux based gui-tool. 
I have the code below. (tcl script)

```
proc Kuser {} {
  echo "AAA" 
}

proc getxy_of_mouse_pointer {} {
  gui_mouse_tool -window Layout.1 -start POINT_DEFINITION_TOOL
  bind . <Button-1> [kuser]
  echo "Hello"
}
```

"gui_mosue_tool" is a built in proc of the tool. 
When executing proc as shown below in the tool, 
"Hello" is output immediately without waiting for Button-1 
tool > getxy_of_mouse_pointer

> AAA 
> Hello

I want to run Kuser-proc when right mouse button is clicked 
I think the bind~ part needs to be modified. 
But I don't know what to do.

bind, event, add etc...

Comment: Could anyone upvote the edits pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[Kuser]` argument to your `bind` is a script substitution - it says: "run this script and replace the `[...]` with the script's result".  So, after the arguments for the `bind` command are resolved, the bind command that gets run is:

```
bind . <Button-1> {}
```

(presuming that the `echo` command returns nothing, and therefore `Kuser`).

You want to give the `bind` command the *name* of the command to run when the event happens, not the result of running that command:

```
bind . <Button-1> Kuser
```

Comment: thanks very much. But when the proc.getxy is called, the kuser-proc is not working. not printed "AAA", only printed "Hello". I'm sorry to ask you so many times.

Comment: I can't see enough context of your problem to know what you mean, I can't guess from the little snippet of code you've posted here.  But you probably want `<Button-3>` for the right mouse button (`<Button-1>` is left).  And you probably want to bind to the event in your main program, not inside `getxy_of_mouse_cursor`, but there really isn't enough context for me to know what you're trying to do.